# Send PATCH request to Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am sending a PATCH request to my DRF server in Postman and it works perfect

However when I do the same in Python I get:

```
<Response [405]> http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/title/8174/
b'{"detail":"Method \\"PATCH\\" not allowed."}'
Method Not Allowed
```

My function that sends data:

```
    ss_token = os.getenv('SS_TOKEN')

    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Token ' + ss_token, 
    }


    source = Source.objects.all().first()
    url = source.url + str(self.ss_id) + '/'
    response = requests.patch(source.url, headers=headers, data={'key':'value'})
    print(response, url)
    print(response.content)
    print(response.reason)
    return True
```

Do I have to send other headers to the API to make the PATCH work?

Comment: Can you provide the view behind the PATCH method? And the request made by Postman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah looks like I made a mistake. Forgot to replace source.url with the new url variable called 'url' variable. Because that add the 'ss_id' at the url' so it becomes 'api/title/ID/' instead of just 'api/title'

```
url = source.url + str(self.ss_id) + '/'
response = requests.patch(url, headers=headers, data={'key':'value'})
```